# Storage manager still shows the steam game Dota2 is install and taking up 40gb even though it is removed (I think)

Tags: macos, storage, monterey, games

Storage manager is showing that Dota2 is taking up 40gb.

I have already deleted it, and it does not show up in Steam or in my applications.

How do I prevent the storage manager (found in About This Mac > Storage > Manage Storage) from counting this app as taking up 40gb.

FYI storage manager shows the delete option for it as greyed out.

How can I correctly update my OS so it does not think that Dota2 is still installed and taking up space?

Comment: Where did you delete it from? Was it a Finder drag to Trash or did you `rm` files using Terminal?

Comment: Can't remember.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot from the storage manager?

Comment: If the application still shows up in the Storage overview, it most likely still is stored somewhere. Did you empty the Trash after removing it, did you try whether restarting Steam or rebooting your Mac solves the problem, did you look into `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps` to see whether it is still there, did you click on the entry in the Storage overview to see the path at the bottom, or right-click to reveal in Finder?

Comment: Also, adding screenshots usually is more useful than describing the content of a window. They help to provide context, others may also see things you didn't.

Comment: The main problem with the question is lack of details, not lack of attention. I've removed the bounty (you should get the reputation back in a few minutes) so you don't waste your reputation.

Comment: What details are missing?

Comment: Please see the comments above. Keep in mind that answers depend on you providing as much details as possible. Currently we only have "I removed a Steam app by unknown means but it still shows up in the Storage list".